# Multivariate datasets comparison in R

Tags: r, variance, multivariate-analysis, covariance, vegan

I would like to compare the variance of two multivariate datasets describing the same population between them (e.g. Covariance) but also the specificity of one dataset regarding the total variance of both multivariate dataset (i.e. variance dataset_1 - covariance dataset 1 & 2, pure white area in my drawing).

[image: As a picture often speaks better than words]

Here below, I build a reproducible example build on the doubs dataset from the `ade4` `R` package:
library(ade4)
# This data set gives environmental variables, fish species and spatial coordinates for 30 sites.
data("doubs")

```
# extracting the environmental variables
env_heterogeneity <- doubs$env
head(env_heterogeneity)

# selecting 2 sets of environmental parameters describing same sites
multivariate_dataset_1 <- env_heterogeneity[,1:4] # physical/morphology parameters
multivariate_dataset_2 <- env_heterogeneity[,5:11] # chemical parameters
```

I can find statistical tools in R to work on the grey zone (see my drawing up here), e.g. the variance partitioning tools, `varpart` from the `vegan` `R` package. This tools allows to estimate the proportion of the variance of multivariate_dataset_1 explained by multivariate_dataset_2.

```
# how  multivariate_dataset_1 can explain the variance of multivariate_dataset_2?
library(vegan)
RDA_1 <- rda(X = multivariate_dataset_1 , Y = multivariate_dataset_2)
summary(RDA_1)
# summary(RDA_1)
# 
# Call:
#   rda(X = multivariate_dataset_1, Y = multivariate_dataset_2) 
# 
# Partitioning of variance:
#   Inertia Proportion
# Total         5300660     1.0000
# Constrained   3786549     0.7144
# Unconstrained 1514111     0.2856
```

I can also work on the co-inertia among my multivariate datasets (for me, same as covariance) with the `ade4` package. This package comes with the `RV.rtest` function which performs a Monte-Carlo Test on the sum of eigenvalues. It can be considered as a multivariate generalization of Pearson correlation coefficient and thus provides a good estimate of the shared variance among multivariate_dataset_1 and multivariate_dataset_2.

```
# how similar to each other the two multivariate datasets?
RV.rtest(multivariate_dataset_1,multivariate_dataset_2) 

# RV.rtest(multivariate_dataset_1,multivariate_dataset_2) 
# Monte-Carlo test
# Call: RV.rtest(df1 = multivariate_dataset_1, df2 = multivariate_dataset_2)
# 
# Observation: 0.3940863 
# 
# Based on 99 replicates
# Simulated p-value: 0.01 
# Alternative hypothesis: greater 
# 
# Std.Obs Expectation    Variance 
# 6.578328982 0.043988310 0.002832357
```

**I'm really interested in knowing to what extent the proportion of the total variance (variance of multivariate_dataset_1 and multivariate_dataset_2) can be exclusively explained by one multivariate dataset (e.g. pure white zone in my drawing, variance dataset 1 - covariance 1/2)?**

Don't hesitate to help me find a better wording for my concerns through comments!